# How to autoimatically restart tmux nested sessions when back online?

Tags: ssh, tmux

I usually open a local tmux session that connects to multiple remote tmux sessions over ssh. These lab machines run continuous regressions.
When the laptop goes to sleep overnight the pipes are broken with the ssh sessions (expected).
The next morning I had to restart each one of the windows manually.
Is there a way for tmux to automatically figures that the machine is back online and tries to reconnect to the ssh sessions in each of these windows?

Somewhat like a vnc viewer that reconnects automatically when the machine is back online.

Comment: Consider having 1 remote session which connects to all the other remote sessions, so you only need to reconnect to 1? Use the scripting builtin to tmux to just run a script to reconnect?

Answer (score 1):

You could just run something like this in each window:

```
while :; do ssh $i tmux a; sleep 1; done
```

Or write a script that checks the windows periodically and uses `respawn-pane` or `respawn-window` to restart them if necessary.